# load selected item as default inside mvc combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have viewmodel for manipulating values inside combobox like these

```
SportViewModel sport = new SportViewModel();
sport.SportGroups = new SelectList(GetAllSportGroups(), "Id", "Name");
```

My view is like these

```
@model Models.SportViewModel
<div>Sport group</div>
<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SportGroupId, Model.SportGroups)</div>
```

and I'm return view like these

```
SportViewModel sport = new SportViewModel();
sport.SportGroups = new SelectList(GetAllSportGroups(), "Id", "Name");
return View(sport);
```

Question is: How can I on edit form load selected item as default value inside combobox (value which was selected on create action) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe SelectList has an overload argument called selectedValue with which you are able to select the default value.

```
New SelectList(db.Employees, "Id", "Name", 1)
```

Check here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.108).aspx